# What does it mean that string and character comparisons in Swift are not locale-sensitive?

Tags: swift, string

I started learning Swift language and I am very curious What does it mean that string and character comparisons in Swift are not locale-sensitive? Does it mean that all the characters are stored in Swift like UTF-8 characters?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*(All code examples updated for Swift 3 now.)*

Comparing Swift strings with `<` does a lexicographical comparison
based on the so-called ["Unicode Normalization Form D"](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) (which can be computed with
`decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`)

For example, the decomposition of

```
"ä" = U+00E4 = LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS
```

is the sequence of two Unicode code points

```
U+0061,U+0308 = LATIN SMALL LETTER A + COMBINING DIAERESIS
```

For demonstration purposes, I have written a small String extension which dumps the
contents of the String as an array of Unicode code points:

```
extension String {
    var unicodeData : String {
        return self.unicodeScalars.map {
            String(format: "%04X", $0.value)
            }.joined(separator: ",")
    }
}
```

Now lets take some strings, sort them with `<`:

```
let someStrings = ["ǟψ", "äψ", "ǟx", "äx"].sorted()
print(someStrings)
// ["a", "ã", "ă", "ä", "ǟ", "b"]
```

and dump the Unicode code points of each string (in original and decomposed
form) in the sorted array:

```
for str in someStrings {
    print("\(str)  \(str.unicodeData)  \(str.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.unicodeData)")
}
```

The output

```
äx  00E4,0078  0061,0308,0078
ǟx  01DF,0078  0061,0308,0304,0078
ǟψ  01DF,03C8  0061,0308,0304,03C8
äψ  00E4,03C8  0061,0308,03C8
```

nicely shows that the comparison is done by a lexicographic ordering of the Unicode
code points in the decomposed form.

This is also true for strings of more than one character, as the following example
shows. With

```
let someStrings = ["ǟψ", "äψ", "ǟx", "äx"].sorted()
```

the output of above loop is

```
äx  00E4,0078  0061,0308,0078
ǟx  01DF,0078  0061,0308,0304,0078
ǟψ  01DF,03C8  0061,0308,0304,03C8
äψ  00E4,03C8  0061,0308,03C8
```

which means that

```
"äx" < "ǟx", but "äψ" > "ǟψ"
```

(which was at least unexpected for me).

Finally let's compare this with a locale-sensitive ordering, for example swedish:

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "sv") // svenska
var someStrings = ["ǟ", "ä", "ã", "a", "ă", "b"]
someStrings.sort {
    $0.compare($1, locale: locale) == .orderedAscending
}

print(someStrings)
// ["a", "ă", "ã", "b", "ä", "ǟ"]
```

As you see, the result is different from the Swift `<` sorting.

Comment: Addition/details ("official" ref.: from open source): from the [String.swift source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/String.swift) we can see that e.g. the `<` operator for `String` is defined as `lhs._compareString(rhs) < 0` (which use `_swift_stdlib_unicode_compare_utf8_utf8`, itself), which we can track via  https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/stubs/UnicodeNormalization.cpp to `ucol_strcollIter` (see `MakeRootCollator` for collator settings) from ICU lib; i.e., using the [unicode collation algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/).

Comment: ... ([link to relevant ICU lib](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucol_8h.html))

Comment: @dfri: Thanks for providing the links, much appreciated. I *think* it was also mentioned somewhere in Apple's documentation, but I cannot find it anymore.

Comment: Happy to help. I also recall I've seen some mention of this in the docs, but no had success when I tried to find it earlier today. Seems like the Swift reference docs change quicker than the stdlib itself, and only by ninja-edits :)

Comment: Your last example confused me as I am Swedish and the order should be `[a, b, å, ä]` (not sure about ă and ã but I guess they should be between a and b) since å and ä are separate letters that comes after z in the Swedish alphabet. After some time I realised that you entered locale identifier "se", which is the country code for Sweden but the language code for Northern Sami. The correct language code for Swedish is "sv" :)

Comment: @LoPoBo: I apologize to all Swedish speaking people! With language code "sv" the result is `["a", "ă", "ã", "b", "ä", "ǟ"]` – does that look correct? I will update the answer tonight (and update it for Swift 3 as well). Thanks for your feedback, much appreciated!

Comment: Yes that seems correct. When I wrote `[a, b, å, ä]` I had mistaken `ǟ` for `å` (they look quite similar in the code font). Only a, b and ä are regular letters of the Swedish alphabet, but the order of the other ones seems logical.

Comment: Does the `<` operator guarantee transitivity (a < b and b < c implies a < c)? I ran into an example where this breaks, and I posted the example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230471/string-comparison-in-swift-is-not-transitive . From your explanation I think it should guarantee transitivity but obviously this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the locale can change the alphabetical order, e.g. a case-sensitive comparison can appear case-insensitive because of the locale, or more generally, the alphabetical order of two strings is different.

Comment: Does it mean that Swift stores its own table of all possible characters or it uses any standard like Unicode, etc?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. It means the same as setting LC_ALL=C which means that we're comparing pure byte-values.

Answer (score 1):

Lexicographical ordering and locale-sensitive ordering can be different. You can see an example of it in this question:
[Sorting scala list equivalent to C# without changing C# order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361938/sorting-scala-list-equivalent-to-c-sharp-without-changing-c-sharp-order/25362345#25362345)

In that specific case the locale-sensitive ordering placed `_` before `1`, whereas in a lexicographical ordering it's the opposite.

Swift comparison uses lexicographical ordering.

Comment: Does lexicographical ordering mean alphabetical order? What about characters from different alphabets (each country has its own alphabet), how it knows what characters to consider as first?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: That's what I thought as well, but all the expressions `"a" < "ä"`, `"ä" < "b"` and `ClosedInterval("a", "b").contains("ä")` return true in my test project.