# Standard way to "clamp" a number between two values in Swift

Tags: swift, clamp

Given:

```
let a = 4.2
let b = -1.3
let c = 6.4
```

I want to know the simplest, Swiftiest way to clamp these values to a given range, say `0...5`, such that:

```
a -> 4.2
b -> 0
c -> 5
```

I know I can do the following:

```
let clamped = min(max(a, 0), 5)
```

Or something like:

```
let clamped = (a < 0) ? 0 : ((a > 5) ? 5 : a)
```

But I was wondering if there were any other ways to do this in Swift—in particular, I want to know (and document on SO, since there doesn't appear to be a question about clamping numbers in Swift) whether there is anything in the Swift standard library intended specifically for this purpose.

There may not be, and if so, that's also an answer I'll happily accept.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

**Swift 4/5**

Extension of `Comparable/Strideable` similar to `ClosedRange.clamped(to:_) -> ClosedRange` from standard Swift library.

```
extension Comparable {
    func clamped(to limits: ClosedRange<Self>) -> Self {
        return min(max(self, limits.lowerBound), limits.upperBound)
    }
}

#if swift(<5.1)
extension Strideable where Stride: SignedInteger {
    func clamped(to limits: CountableClosedRange<Self>) -> Self {
        return min(max(self, limits.lowerBound), limits.upperBound)
    }
}
#endif
```

**Usage:**

```
15.clamped(to: 0...10) // returns 10
3.0.clamped(to: 0.0...10.0) // returns 3.0
"a".clamped(to: "g"..."y") // returns "g"

// this also works (thanks to Strideable extension)
let range: CountableClosedRange<Int> = 0...10
15.clamped(to: range) // returns 10
```

Comment: Your example works with just the Comparable extension - the Strideable extension is redundant here unless there is another use case not demonstrated?

Comment: Strideable extension is used for clamping to CountableClosedRange. In case you are using range literal compiler can create proper range type, but if you use variable as a param, Strideable extension is needed. I'll extend the example.

Comment: @OndrejStocek It seems that the `Strideable` extension is no longer required with Swift 5.1.

Comment: I truly advise against the "min/max" idiom.  It is **trick programming**. The one and only reason to do it, is, because it looks clever.  Just one problem: Note that - in fact - here and now glancing at that code I literally **don't know** if the ends are inclusive/exclusive, and/or whether or not it deals w/ float equality issues.  Again: literally the ONLY reason to do that is because it "looks clever".  It achieves utterly nothing and leads to confusion and questions.  It is **NOT a case of "elegant short code"**. I strongly advise against it.

Comment: @Fattie That's the point of this extension - to reduce min/max usage to minimum. In all other cases you can use `.clamped(to: ...)` instead of `min(max(...)...)`

Comment: @Fattie So what is the proper way to do it? And actually, you do know that the range includes the bounds because of the `...` closed range operator.

Comment: Simple and consice, this is perfect!

Answer (score 63):

The [ClosedInterval](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ClosedInterval_Structure/index.html) type already has a

```
func clamp(_ intervalToClamp: ClosedInterval<Bound>) -> ClosedInterval<Bound>
```

method which takes another *interval* as an argument. There is a 
proposal on the Swift evolution mailing list

- [Add clamp(value: Bound) -> Bound to ClosedInterval](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160215/010549.html)

to add another method which clamps a *single value* to the given interval:

```
/// Returns `value` clamped to `self`.
func clamp(value: Bound) -> Bound
```

and that is exactly what you need.

Using the implementation of the existing `clamp()` method at

- https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Interval.swift.gyb

as an example, this additional `clamp()` method can be implemented as

```
extension ClosedInterval {
    func clamp(value : Bound) -> Bound {
        return self.start > value ? self.start
            : self.end < value ? self.end
            : value
    }
}
```

Example:

```
(0.0 ... 5.0).clamp(4.2)    // 4.2
(0.0 ... 5.0).clamp(-1.3)   // 0.0
(0.0 ... 5.0).clamp(6.4)    // 5.0
```

`ClosedInterval` is a *generic* type

```
public struct ClosedInterval<Bound : Comparable> { ... }
```

therefore this works not only for `Double` but for all
types which are `Comparable` (like `Int`, `CGFloat`, `String`, ...):

```
(1 ... 3).clamp(10)      // 3
("a" ... "z").clamp("ä") // "ä"
```

---

Update for **Swift 3 (Xcode 8):** `ClosedInterval` has been renamed
to `ClosedRange`, and its properties are `lower/upperBound` now:

```
extension ClosedRange {
    func clamp(_ value : Bound) -> Bound {
        return self.lowerBound > value ? self.lowerBound
            : self.upperBound < value ? self.upperBound
            : value
    }
}
```

Comment: Fabulous! This is exactly the kind of information I was looking for. Would love to see this implemented in future versions of Swift.

Comment: As a native Swede, (alphabet: `..., x, y, z, å, ä, ö`), `"ä" < "z" // true` is a bit confusing ;) on another note, the `clamp` examples listed will need to be used with external parameter name `value` for the Swift 3 example, possibly worth mentioning explicitly (or Xcode will fix that prompt!).

Comment: @dfri: String and character comparison is *not* locale sensitive, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713975/what-does-it-mean-that-string-and-character-comparisons-in-swift-are-not-locale. Added `_` external parameter name to make the examples work again. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 31):

Using the same syntax as Apple to do the min and max operator:

```
public func clamp<T>(_ value: T, minValue: T, maxValue: T) -> T where T : Comparable {
    return min(max(value, minValue), maxValue)
}
```

You can use as that:

```
let clamped = clamp(newValue, minValue: 0, maxValue: 1)
```

The cool thing about this approach is that any value defines the necessary type to do the operation, so the compiler handles that itself.

Comment: this is the answer in which i'd have the greatest confidence of it not needing maintenance as the years go by.

Answer (score 19):

## 2020. The extremely simple way.

```swift
extension Comparable {
    func clamped(_ f: Self, _ t: Self)  ->  Self {
        var r = self
        if r < f { r = f }
        if r > t { r = t }
        // (use SIMPLE, EXPLICIT code here to make it utterly clear
        // whether we are inclusive, what form of equality, etc etc)
        return r
    }
}
```

While I **truly love** ranges in Swift, I really think the absolutely standard syntax for a clamp function ("for 50 years now in every computer language") is just simpler and better:

```
x = x.clamped(0.5, 5.0)
```

Until it is built-in to Swift, really I think that's best.

Philosophical corner:

IMO the two values in a clamp function *are not really a 'range'* - they're just "two values".

(Just for example: it's completely common in game code to have the two dynamic values sometimes be in the "wrong order" (i.e., the desired result is something outside) or the same (the result is just that value).)

## An opinion on end-naming ...

On everything we do, we insist on explicitly stating whether inclusive or exclusive.  For example if there's a call

```
randomIntUpTo( 13 )
```

in fact we will name it

```
randomIntUpToExclusive( 13 )
```

or indeed "inclusive" if that is the case. Or depending on the language something like

```
randomInt(fromInclusive:  upToExclusive: )
```

or whatever the case may be.  In this way there is absolutely never ever ever a unity error, and nothing needs to be discussed.  All code names should be self-documenting.  So indeed, for us, the function above would be named

```
func clamped(fromExclusive: Self, toExclusive: Self)
```

or whatever describes it.

But that's just us.  But it's the right thing to do :)

Comment: You make a good point about ranges not necessarily being relevant to clamping, and about the order of the two clamp values.
A shorter version of your implementation might be:
`func clamped(_ a: Self, _ b: Self)  ->  Self {
    max(min(self, a), b)
}
`

Comment: it is not simple because you create extra variable but you could return the value directly

Comment: hi @VyachaslavGerchicov - that's very much the point!  do it the simplest, clearest, most explicit way.  *not* the shortest or most concise way

Comment: This answer doesn't utilises anything new that was added in 2020. And also doesn't contribute to existing answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I totally disagree @kelin  nothing, but nothing, is more important in real-world software engineering than style idiom and approach.  Reusability, readability, and reliability start with a KISS approach to the simplest things. indeed that's why this is a great question.  As the person states it is trivial to do the operation at hand, thje question is what is the "standard", "best" way to do it.

Answer (score 9):

With **Swift 5.1**, the idiomatic way to achieve the desired clamping would be with [property wrappers](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#clamping-a-value-within-bounds). A touched-up example from [NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/propertywrapper/):

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Clamping<Value: Comparable> {
  var value: Value
  let range: ClosedRange<Value>

  init(wrappedValue: Value, _ range: ClosedRange<Value>) {
    precondition(range.contains(wrappedValue))
    self.value = wrappedValue
    self.range = range
  }

  var wrappedValue: Value {
    get { value }
    set { value = min(max(range.lowerBound, newValue), range.upperBound) }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Clamping(0...5) var a: Float = 4.2
@Clamping(0...5) var b: Float = -1.3
@Clamping(0...5) var c: Float = 6.4
```

Comment: This seems so much verbose and unintuitive to me! `let x = 1.42.clamped(to: 0...1)` or `let x = clamp(1.42, to: 0...1)` is cleaner than `@Clamping(0...1) let x = 1.42`.

Comment: Very interesting solution. Thanks.

Comment: @LouisLac it's more verbose but the increased verbosity comes with the benefit of communicating to the reader that they may have their values clamped. If you are a newcomer to the codebase this is incredibly valuable.

Answer (score 9):

The shortest (but maybe not most efficient) way to clamp, is:

```
let clamped = [0, a, 5].sorted()[1]
```

Source: user tobr in a [discussion on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24223458)

Answer (score 8):

In Swift 3 there are new `CountableClosedRange`, `CountableRange`, `Range`, `ClosedRange` protocols. They have the same `upperBound` and `lowerBound` properties. So you can extend all `Range` protocols at once with a `clamp` method by declaring a custom protocol:

```
protocol ClampableRange {

    associatedtype Bound : Comparable

    var upperBound: Bound { get }

    var lowerBound: Bound { get }

}

extension ClampableRange {

    func clamp(_ value: Bound) -> Bound {
        return min(max(lowerBound, value), upperBound)
    }  

}

extension Range : ClampableRange {}
extension ClosedRange : ClampableRange {}
extension CountableRange : ClampableRange {}
extension CountableClosedRange : ClampableRange {}
```

Usage:

```
(0...10).clamp(12) // 10
(0..<100).clamp(-2) // 0
("a"..."c").clamp("z") // c
```

Comment: `(0..<100).clamp(123)` returns `100` which *might* be unexpected because that number is not included in the interval.

Comment: Above problem exists for all example implementations!

Comment: This is good reason to implement clamping for closed ranges only.

Answer (score 8):

Following up on @Fattie's answer and my comment, here's my suggestion for clarity:

```
extension Comparable {
    func clamped(_ a: Self, _ b: Self) -> Self {
        min(max(self, a), b)
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear I personally do not recommend this (as explained in my answer/comments)

Answer (score 2):

Extending `FixedWidthInteger` and creating an instance generic method to accept a `RangeExpression` and taking care of the edge cases:

```
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    func clamped<R: RangeExpression>(with range: R) -> Self where R.Bound == Self {
        switch range {
        case let range as ClosedRange<Self>:
            return Swift.min(range.upperBound, Swift.max(range.lowerBound, self))
        case let range as PartialRangeFrom<Self>:
            return Swift.max(range.lowerBound, self)
        case let range as PartialRangeThrough<Self>:
            return Swift.min(range.upperBound, self)
        case let range as Range<Self>:
            return Swift.min(range.dropLast().upperBound, Swift.max(range.lowerBound, self))
        case let range as PartialRangeUpTo<Self>:
            return Swift.min(range.upperBound.advanced(by: -1), self)
        default: return self
        }
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
100.clamped(with: 1...)     // 100
100.clamped(with: ..<100)   // 99
100.clamped(with: ...100)   // 100
100.clamped(with: 1..<100)  // 99
100.clamped(with: 1...100)  // 100

0.clamped(with: 1...)       // 1
0.clamped(with: ..<100)     // 0
0.clamped(with: ...100)     // 0
0.clamped(with: 1..<100)    // 1
0.clamped(with: 1...100)    // 1
```

---

To achieve the same results with a FloatingPoint implementation you can use its nextDown property for the edge cases:

```
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {
    func clamped<R: RangeExpression>(with range: R) -> Self where R.Bound == Self {
        switch range {
        case let range as ClosedRange<Self>:
            return Swift.min(range.upperBound, Swift.max(range.lowerBound, self))
        case let range as PartialRangeFrom<Self>:
            return Swift.max(range.lowerBound, self)
        case let range as PartialRangeThrough<Self>:
            return Swift.min(range.upperBound, self)
        case let range as Range<Self>:
            return Swift.min(range.upperBound.nextDown, Swift.max(range.lowerBound, self))
        case let range as PartialRangeUpTo<Self>:
            return Swift.min(range.upperBound.nextDown, self)
        default: return self
        }
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let value = 100.0

value.clamped(with: 1...)     // 100
value.clamped(with: ..<100)   // 99.99999999999999
value.clamped(with: ...100)   // 100
value.clamped(with: 1..<100)  // 99.99999999999999
value.clamped(with: 1...100)  // 100
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it counter-intuitive thinking about how to clamp a value only from one side: `min()` clamps a value to an upper bound, and `max()` clamps a value to a lower bound. So adding to the other answers, I use an extension that allows to clamp a value to a range as well as a lower and an upper bound.

```
extension Comparable {
    
    func clamped(range: ClosedRange<Self>) -> Self {
        return max(range.lowerBound, min(self, range.upperBound))
    }
    
    func clamped(lowerBound: Self) -> Self {
        return max(lowerBound, self)
    }
    
    func clamped(upperBound: Self) -> Self {
        return min(self, upperBound)
    }
    
}
```