# In Swift, How to extend a protocol with generic type?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, extension-methods

I want to add a function to all the classes that implement Comparable , such as Int, Float, CGFloat. Here is my code with error reported:

```
extension Comparable{
    func constraintBetween<T: Comparable>(a:T , b: T) -> T{
        if self < a {
            return a
        }else if self > b{
            return b
        }else{
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
Anyone can help to make it right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related (what you're implementing is a _clamp_ method): [Standard way to “clamp” a number between two values in Sw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110620/standard-way-to-clamp-a-number-between-two-values-in-swift).

Comment: @dfri All right. But I did search before I asked.

Comment: No worries, I'm not even certain its a duplicate, but it should at least be related and possibly helpful for you.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289169/in-swift-how-to-extension-a-protocol-with-generic-type

Comment: Int, Float, CGFloat are not classes.

Comment: @LeoNatan ,yeah, they are structs in SWIFT. Not much deferent from classes.

Comment: There is plenty difference between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Self` is the stand-in for the type adopting the protocol:

```
extension Comparable {
    func constraintBetween(a: Self, b: Self) -> Self {
        if self < a {
            return a
        } else if self > b {
            return b
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```