# Replace values in an ArraySlice<Float>

Tags: arrays, swift

I tried to filter an `ArraySlice<Float>`to replace the values below -5000 and higher 5000 to -5000 and 5000.
I can apply one condition but how I can apply both condition in a same time?
I want to add that if the value is higher than 5000, replace it with 5000, how I can do that?

```
 filteredData.append(contentsOf: data.map({ return $0 < -5000 ? -5000 : $0}))
```

Comment: That is called *clamping* – see [Standard way to “clamp” a number between two values in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110620/standard-way-to-clamp-a-number-between-two-values-in-swift) for various approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use an `if-else` statement to check both conditions

```
let filteredData = floatData.map { value -> Float in
    if value > 5000 {
        return 5000
    } else if value < -5000 {
        return -5000
    } else {
        return value
    }
}
```

Or you can use the combination of `min` and `max` to limit your values to a specified range.

```
let filteredData = floatData.map { value -> Float in max(min(value, 5000), -5000) }
```

Comment: this is wrong. you are returning the negative value for both conditions. Btw you could use pattern. match operator `-5000...5000 ~= $0 ? $0 : value` but thats not the case here

Comment: this also assumes that filteredData is empty which might not be true

Comment: @LeoDabus my bad, misread the question. As for omitting the `append`, I just created a minimal reproducible example in a playground, if OP needs the `append`, it should be easy to change.

Comment: Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 0):

According to the task conditions, let's do it:

```
filteredData.append(contentsOf: data.map({ $0 < -5000 ? -5000 : $0 > 5000 ? 5000 : $0}))
```