# ClosedInterval<String> to [String] in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string

Why is it that:

```
let i = 1...100
let s = [Int](i)
```

yields

```
[1, 2, 3, ..., 100]
```

but

```
let i = "a"..."z"
let s = [String](i)
```

yields

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type '[String]' with an argument list of type '(ClosedInterval<String>)'
```

yet

```
i.contains("b")
```

yields

```
true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Int` conforms to `ForwardIndexType`, therefore in

```
let i = 1...100
```

`...` is the operator

```
public func ...<Pos : ForwardIndexType where Pos : Comparable>(start: Pos, end: Pos) -> Range<Pos>
```

and the result is a `Range<Int>`. Ranges are collections and sequences:
One can enumerate the elements of the range and create an array from it.

But `String` and `Character` do not conform to `ForwardIndexType`:
There is no method to advance from one string or character to the next.
Therefore in

```
let i = "a"..."z"
```

`...` is the operator

```
public func ...<Bound : Comparable>(start: Bound, end: Bound) -> ClosedInterval<Bound>
```

and the result is a `ClosedInterval<String>`. You can check if a 
particular string is contained in that interval, but you can not
enumerate its elements.

`"a"..."z"` represents all strings `s` for which `"a" <= s <= "z"`
according to the Unicode standard, and not just the 26 lowercase letters
from the english alphabet, compare e.g. [What does it mean that string and character comparisons in Swift are not locale-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713975/what-does-it-mean-that-string-and-character-comparisons-in-swift-are-not-locale). For example

```
let c = i.contains("ä")
```

yields `true`.

In Swift 3, the range and interval types have been renamed and
reorganized:

```
"1" ... "100"  // CountableClosedRange<Int>
"a" ... "z"    // ClosedRange<String>
```

If your intention is to create an array with all characters from
"a" to "z" according to their ordering in the Unicode tables then
you can enumerate the `UTF-32` code units:

```
let i = UnicodeScalar("a").value ... UnicodeScalar("z").value
let charArray = (i.map { Character(UnicodeScalar($0)) })
// or
let stringArray = (i.map { String(UnicodeScalar($0)) })
```

The result is

```
["a", "b", "c", ... , "z"]
```

as an array of `Character` or an array of `String`.