# How does the Swift string more than operator work

Tags: ios, swift

I was reading the documentation on the Swift programming language, when I came across [the following code snippet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94):

```
let names = ["Chris", "Alex", "Ewa", "Barry", "Daniella"]

func backwards(s1: String, _ s2: String) -> Bool {
   return s1 > s2
}

names.sort(backwards) // ["Ewa", "Daniella", "Chris", "Barry", "Alex"]
```

What I don't seem to be able to find, is how the `>` operator works in this context, I thought it would do something like count the amount of characters and then return a boolean based on that, but with that logic the following snippet should return false:

```
"CD" > "ABC" // true
```

Could someone please explain what is going on here?

Comment: what is your current knowledge / understanding of string comparison?

Comment: @Wain I've only ever used basic `==`, `===`, `!=` in other languages, so seeing a more than / less than being used is quite new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe javascript uses exactly the same string comparison approach, and the same syntax. In javascript you could also use `localeCompare()`. And in swift you could alternatively use `localizedCompare(_:)` (or one of the other string comparison functions). They're all different ways, and with different options, to alphabetically compare strings.

Comment: Addition, Swift 2.2.30: from the [String.swift source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/String.swift) we can see that e.g. the `<` operator for `String` is defined as `lhs._compareString(rhs) < 0` (which use `_swift_stdlib_unicode_compare_utf8_utf8`, itself), which we can track via  https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/stubs/UnicodeNormalization.cpp to `ucol_strcollIter` (see `MakeRootCollator` for collator) from [ICU lib](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucol_8h.html); i.e., using [unicode collation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/).

Answer (score 1):

Swift does lexicographical string comparison. This has been asked before you can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25775112/6543229)