# How String Comparison happens in Swift

Tags: swift, string

in this example:

```
var str1 = "hello"
var str2 = "Hello"

if str1 < str2 { print("hello is less than Hello")}
else {print("hello is more than Hello")}
```

on what basis it is found that str1 is greater than str2?

Comment: Related: [What does it mean that string and character comparisons in Swift are not locale-sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713975/what-does-it-mean-that-string-and-character-comparisons-in-swift-are-not-locale)

Comment: isn't it really obvious that as `H` has ascii decimal value `72` and `h` has the ascii decimal value `104`. So as like `strcmp` in **C** on the first index `h` is greater than `H` which why the outcome is so.

Answer (score 12):

Swift strings are compared according to the
[Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/),
which means that (effectively),

- each string is put into ["Unicode Normalization Form D"](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms),
- the unicode scalar values of these "decomposed" strings are compared lexicographically.

In your example, `"hello`" and `"Hello"` have the Unicode values

```
hello: U+0068, U+0065, U+006C, U+006C, U+006F 
Hello: U+0048, U+0065, U+006C, U+006C, U+006F
```

and therefore `"Hello" < "hello"`.

The "normalization" or "decomposing" is relevant e.g. for characters
with diacritical marks. As an example,

```
a = U+0061
ä = U+00E4
b = U+0062
```

have the decomposed form

```
a: U+0061
ä: U+0061, U+0308  // LATIN SMALL LETTER A + COMBINING DIAERESIS
b: U+0062
```

and therefore `"a" < "ä" < "b"`.

For more details and examples, see [What does it mean that string and character comparisons in Swift are not locale-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713975/what-does-it-mean-that-string-and-character-comparisons-in-swift-are-not-locale)

Answer (score 8):

The two strings are compared, character by character, using each character's Unicode value. Since `h` has a higher code (U+0068) than `H` (U+0048), `str1` is "greater" than `str2`.

Based on Martin's comment below the question, it's slightly more complex than I stated. Please see [What does it mean that string and character comparisons in Swift are not locale-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713975/what-does-it-mean-that-string-and-character-comparisons-in-swift-are-not-locale) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is based on the Lexicographical Order.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.2 - 
//Unicode Value gives you an idea why "hello" is greater than "Hello" as the length of both Strings are the same.

```
var str1 = "hello"
var str2 = "Hello"

if (str1 < str2){
    print("hello is less than Hello")
}
else {
    print("hello is more than Hello")
}

print(str1.unicodeScalars[str1.unicodeScalars.startIndex].value)
print(str2.unicodeScalars[str2.unicodeScalars.startIndex].value)
```