# How does Swift know the English alphabet?

Tags: swift, syntax

Documentation > Swift > ClosedRange

```
let values = "a"..."z"
print(values.contains("c")) //true
```

Could someone please explain why this prints true?

Comment: That's essentially just doing `("a" <= "c") && ("c" <= "z")`.  So your question essentially becomes "how does string comparison work?".

Comment: I think the question is more for the first line.

Comment: So there is an implementation of Comparable somewhere ? On String?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/2427762 seems like the thing.

Comment: Yes that is the comparable protocol. So is there an implementation of that on String for the English alphabet?

Comment: Compare [How String Comparison happens in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38910106/2976878). It's based on a lexicographic comparison of unicode scalar values when the string is put into Unicode Normalisation Form D. For a single ASCII letter, that's just a straightforward comparison of unicode scalars for those letters.

Comment: This answered my question http://stackoverflow.com/a/25775112/1951992