# Swift how to sort dict keys by byte value and not alphabetically?

Tags: swift, linux, macos, dictionary, swift3

I'm using a for loop to create a string of a dicts keys and values.
Unfortunately swift behaves differently on Mac and Linux.

`for key in parameters.keys.sorted() {...}`

I want to sort my keys by byte value, not alphabetically, lowercase parameters should be listed after uppercase ones.

So a key like "AWT" should come before a key like "Ast".

Comment: On Apple platforms you'll get the desired order. On Linux that is a known bug which should be fixed in Swift 4, see https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-530.  – Note that this has nothing to do with dictionaries or keys, but only how the comparison of strings is implemented, `print(["AWT", "Ast"].sorted())` is sufficient to see the difference between Apple and Linux.

Comment: .sorted() can take parameters "sorted using the given predicate as the comparison between elements". Is there a way to manually achieve the right sorting?

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify first what "sort  by byte value" means for you exactly.

Comment: okay, for me it means that when looked up: http://www.asciitable.com/ so the decimal value of a uppercase "W" comes before a lowercase "a". So like in the ascii table, i would like to sort it. Compared to my example, with "AWT" and "Ast" both start with an "A" so equal, but then "W" comes before "a".

Comment: What about non-ASCII characters? On Apple platforms, "a" < "ä" < "b", "e" < "é" < "f".

Comment: non-ASCII characters won't occur here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Apple platforms, Swift strings comparison is a lexicographical comparison of Unicode scalar values, based on the so-called "Unicode Normalization Form D", see 
[How String Comparison happens in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910106/how-string-comparison-happens-in-swift) or [What does it mean that string and character comparisons in Swift are not locale-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713975/what-does-it-mean-that-string-and-character-comparisons-in-swift-are-not-locale) for details.

On Linux, the sort order is different. That is a known problem
([[String] sort order varies on Darwin vs. Linux](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-530)) and should be fixed in Swift 4.

If you only care about ASCII characters then a possible approach would
be to compare the UTF-8 representation of the strings:

```
func utf8StringCompare(s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool {
    let u1 = s1.utf8
    let u2 = s2.utf8
    for (x, y) in zip(u1, u2) {
        if x < y { return true }
        if x > y { return false }
    }
    return u1.count < u2.count
}


let s = ["AWT", "Ast"].sorted(by: utf8StringCompare)
print(s) // ["AWT", "Ast"]
```

This gives identical results on Apple platforms and on Linux.

But note that this is *not* the default sort order for Swift Strings
on Apple platforms. To replicate that on Linux (before it is fixed in Swift 4), the following
algorithm would work:

```
func unicodeStringCompare(s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool {
    let u1 = s1.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.unicodeScalars
    let u2 = s2.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.unicodeScalars
    for (x, y) in zip(u1, u2) {
        if x.value < y.value { return true }
        if x.value > y.value { return false }
    }
    return u1.count < u2.count
}

let someStrings = ["a", "b", "e", "f", "ä", "é"].sorted(by: unicodeStringCompare)
print(someStrings) // ["a", "ä", "b", "e", "é", "f"]
```