# Sort Array by Dates stored as Strings

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, date

I have a custom Post object that stores the date the post was created and using Firestore, all date objects get stored as String values.

I have a screen that displays all the posts on a tableview by retrieving the data from the database to create custom Post objects and then adding them to a custom array that stores posts

var postArray: Post

As mentioned, each post has a date stored as a string. How do I sort the array by date (string)?

Comment: Override the "equal" function (within which the string will be converted to date and then equalized)

Comment: Do you have an example or something you can point me to? @baruch

Comment: It depends on the date format of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare string with `>` , `<` signs by default, as they are compared by [UNICODE COLLATION ALGORITHM](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/) by default.

For more details see @Martin R 's answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38910703/6315441

Now if all the dates are in any one format this would work

```
let sortedPostArray = postArray.sorted(by: { $0.date > $1.date})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a computed property in Post struct/class to get date value from the string

```
struct Post {
    var dateString: String
    private let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    var date: Date? {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"//Change date format as per your string
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    }
}
```

Then you can sort the array by this value

```
let sortedArray = postArray.sorted { $0.date ?? .distantFuture < $1.date ?? .distantFuture}
```

Comment: Date formatters are notoriously (computationally) expensive. You really don’t want to instantiate them inside computed properties. Instantiate only one date formatter and use it repeatedly. Also, if the date is in ISO8601 format, like you suggest here, I’d consider [`ISO8601DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter).

Comment: @Rob I thought to use ISO8601DateFormatter but Im not sure about OP's date format