# What is the difference between sorting an array of strings by localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare and default Comparable?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting

I declared the following array in my playground

```
var stringArray = ["a","A","@c","&","!","f","G","h"]
```

when I tried to sort it using (since String conforms to [Comparable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable))

```
stringArray = stringArray.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
```

I got the following result

> ["!", "&", "@c", "A", "G", "a", "f", "h"]

however, if I declared it as

```
stringArray = stringArray.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
```

I will get a different result

> ["!", "@c", "&", "A", "a", "f", "G", "h"]

The results are not the same.

Why this behavior happens?

Comment: Related: [What does it mean that string and character comparisons in Swift are not locale-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713975/what-does-it-mean-that-string-and-character-comparisons-in-swift-are-not-locale)

Answer (score 1):

Different locales may have different sorting orders for characters. You should use this when you are presenting a sorted list to the user.

Using `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` makes sure that if you have a list that you are presenting to the user, it is sorted using the current locale, in a way that the user expects.