# Not getting max element of array

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have a string array called `prodIDArr` having values like so...

```
["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
```

But when I do something like so..

```
let maxVal = prodIDArr.max()
```

I get the value of `maxVal` as 9 and not 10.

What could be the reason for this...?

Comment: Because that are *strings,* not numbers.

Comment: But @Martin R how did it then consider the values till 9

Comment: Strings are compared lexicographically: "1" < "10" < "2" < ... < "9"

Comment: I'm sorry @MartinR But what does lexicographically mean..?

Comment: It's the order that elements (for example words) would appear in a lexicon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: `xicographically` is alphabetic order in  alphabetic  string start with 1 less than string start with 9

Comment: ok..Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an array of strings, and those are compared [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order):

```
"1" < "10" < "2" < ... < "9"
```

For example `"10" < "2"` because the initial characters already
satisfy `"1" < "2"`. (For the gory details, see for example
[What does it mean that string and character comparisons in Swift are not locale-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713975/what-does-it-mean-that-string-and-character-comparisons-in-swift-are-not-locale).)

Using an array of integers would be the best solution:

```
let prodIDArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let maxId = prodIDArr.max()
print(maxId) // Optional(10)
```

If that is not possible then you can enforce a numeric comparison with

```
let prodIDArr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
let maxId = prodIDArr.max(by: { $0.compare($1, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending })
print(maxId) // Optional("10")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also map your original String Array to an Int Array

```
let prodIDArr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
let prodNumArray = prodIDArr.map { input in Int(input)!} // or { Int($0)! }
print(prodNumArray.max()!)
```